# jquery templates - how to code unescaped buffering with node.js and Express

Tags: node.js, express, jquery-templates

When I use:

```
app.set('view options', {layout:true});
```

in express, <%- body %> is unescaped buffering for ejs and body!= body is unescaped buffering for jade.  How do I do this for jquery templates?  Thanks.

Comment: It's been a while now, 1 year at the time i'm writing, did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to call the variable directly?

```
<div>#{body}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
p!= body
```